# Egeloen IvoryGoogleMapBundle ApI Key Error

Tags: php, symfony, google-maps

I am using [egeloen's IvoryGoogleMapBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle) and I have run all commands like

```
$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle
$ composer require egeloen/serializer-bundle
$ composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter
$ composer require php-http/httplug-bundle
```

I have included below three lines code in appkernel.

```
new Ivory\GoogleMapBundle\IvoryGoogleMapBundle(),

  // Optionally
  new Ivory\SerializerBundle\IvorySerializerBundle(),
  new Http\HttplugBundle\HttplugBundle(),
```

Also, I have generated API keys as well.

Unfortunately, the places API is not working and giving following error
in the console

```
" Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the bundle to use your API key?

```
ivory_google_map:
    map:
        api_key: yourapikey
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/1fc4cc3330fb267152100d681cf296022535ec5d/Resources/doc/map.md#api-key)